# How to un-flatten a list

Tags: haskell

I can flatten a nested data structure with ease, but the dual operation seems awfully difficult (at least for me).

Given a List of type `[(a,b,c)]`, how can I create a nested structure, i.e.

```
unflatten :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a,b,c)] -> [(a, [(b, [c])])]
```

such that each `a` only occurs only once and likewise each combination of `(a,b)`

I don't quite know why I am struggling with this, because the dual operation is really simple

```
flatten :: [(a, [(b, [c])])] -> [(a,b,c)]
flatten xs = [(a,b,c) | (a,bcs) <- xs, (b,cs) <- bcs, c<-cs]
```

**Update**

Following EricR's suggestion I wrote a function which does one level of un-flattening, but I am still struggling to extend it

```
grp :: Ord b => [(b,c)] -> [(b,[c])]
grp xs = do
    b <- (nub . sort . map fst) xs 
    let cs = [c' | (b',c') <- xs, b'==b]
    return (b,cs)
```

Comment: If you have no constraint - on a, b, c this is not possible but you should have a look at `groupBy`

Comment: Can you write or do you have available a simpler group-by function, i.e. `[(a,b)] -> [ (a, [b]) ]`?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I added the constraints. I don't think I need a constraint on c though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following ErikR's advice, a pattern emerged how to extend it to longer and longer tuples.

```
-- construct some raw material
l a i = map ((a ++) . show) [1..i]
l4 = [(a,b,c,d) | d<-l "d" 3, c <- l "c" 3, b<-l "b" 3, a<-l "a" 2 ]

grp2 :: Ord a => [(a,b)] -> [(a,[b])]
grp2 xs = do
    a <- (nub . sort . map fst) xs 
    let bs = [b' | (a',b') <- xs, a'==a]
    return (a,bs)

grp3 :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a,b,c)] -> [(a,[(b,[c])])]
grp3 ys = do
    (a, bcs) <- grp2 (map split3 ys)
    return (a, grp2 bcs)
          where
              split3 (a,b,c) = (a,(b,c))

grp4 :: (Ord a, Ord b, Ord c) => [(a,b,c,d)] -> [(a,[(b,[(c,[d])])])]
grp4 zs = do
    (a, bcds) <- grp2 (map split4 zs)
    return (a, grp3 bcds)
          where
              split4 (a,b,c,d) = (a,(b,c,d))
```

Now

```
*Main> pp $ grp4 l4
```

Prints

```
[ ( "a1"
  , [ ( "b1"
      , [ ( "c1" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c2" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c3" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        ]
      )
    , ( "b2"
      , [ ( "c1" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c2" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c3" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        ]
      )
    , ( "b3"
      , [ ( "c1" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c2" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c3" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        ]
      )
    ]
  )
, ( "a2"
  , [ ( "b1"
      , [ ( "c1" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c2" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c3" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        ]
      )
    , ( "b2"
      , [ ( "c1" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c2" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c3" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        ]
      )
    , ( "b3"
      , [ ( "c1" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c2" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        , ( "c3" , [ "d1" , "d2" , "d3" ] )
        ]
      )
    ]
  )
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd put that data into a nested map. You can always pull it out again into nested association lists afterwards.

First convert each item into a (small) nested map with 1 element in the list `[c]`:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.List

triplesToMaps :: [(a,b,c)] -> [M.Map a (M.Map b [c])]
triplesToMaps = map (\(a,b,c) -> M.singleton a (M.singleton b [c]))
```

then combine them all using `unionWith`

```
combineMaps :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [M.Map a (M.Map b [c])] -> M.Map a (M.Map b [c])
combineMaps = foldl' (M.unionWith (M.unionWith (++))) M.empty
```

and then, if you want, bring it back to lists:

```
flattenToLists :: M.Map a (M.Map b [c]) -> [(a,[(b,[c])])]
flattenToLists = M.assocs . (M.map M.assocs)
```

Example:

```
> flattenToLists . combineMaps . triplesToMaps $ [(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,3,5),(2,6,8)]
[(1,[(2,[3,4]),(3,[5])]),(2,[(6,[8])])]
```

In practice you probably wouldn't `flattenToLists` because the nested map is the more useful structure.

Incidentally, if `Map` had the "right" Monoid structure then `M.unionWith (M.unionWith (++))` would just be `mappend`, and the whole thing could be `foldMap (\(a,b,c) -> M.singleton a (M.singleton b [c]))`.

[edited : added the dual as in the question]

Oh, and to go back to `[(a,b,c)]` two approaches spring to mind. The list comprehension just like yours, but using `assocs`:

```
flatten :: M.Map a (M.Map b [c]) -> [(a,b,c)]
flatten m = [(a,b,c) | (a,bcs) <- M.assocs m, (b,cs) <- M.assocs bcs, c <- cs]
```

or the version using foldMap:

```
flatten' :: M.Map a (M.Map b [c]) -> [(a,b,c)]
flatten' = M.foldMapWithKey (\a -> M.foldMapWithKey (\b -> foldMap (\c -> [(a,b,c)])))
```